# FFMPEG: [flv @ 0xbeee10] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp

I'm using FFMPEG to take my IP camera's RTSP stream and send it to my streaming server as RTMP. When I run the command, I get 5 of the below error and then the stream does start. However, if I let it go overnight, it will stop streaming and fill up terminal with this error as well.

```
[flv @ 0x191ba0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -202; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

Is there something wrong with my FFMPEG command?

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://redact@192.168.10.112:redact_port/live0.264 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/ipcam
ffmpeg version N-87747-g123f6dc Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-gpl --prefix=/usr --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-version3 --disable-mmx
  libavutil      55. 77.101 / 55. 77.101
  libavcodec     57.106.104 / 57.106.104
  libavformat    57. 82.102 / 57. 82.102
  libavdevice    57.  9.101 / 57.  9.101
  libavfilter     6.106.101 /  6.106.101
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://redact@192.168.10.112:redact_port/live0.264':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session Streamed by LIBZRTSP
    comment         : live0.264
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.242000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 25 fps, 24.83 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/ipcam':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session Streamed by LIBZRTSP
    comment         : live0.264
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, q=2-31, 25 fps, 24.83 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_mulaw ([8][0][0][0] / 0x0008), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[flv @ 0xbeee10] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -202; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xbeee10] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -162; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xbeee10] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -121; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xbeee10] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -81; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xbeee10] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -41; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[flv @ 0xbeee10] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -1; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=321421 fps= 25 q=-1.0 size= 1190616kB time=03:36:01.31 bitrate= 752.5kbits/s speed=   1x
```

Answer (score 4):

I used **-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1** and **-r 15** (15 is FPS) on my input stream. I also added **-r 15** on all my output streams.

The biggest culprit was the cameras I was using.  I have a maximum bitrate instead of variable.  I disabled dynamic GOP and dynamic fps.  I also went ahead and upgraded to FFMPEG 4 which came out 4/20 (after your original post).  I used Ubuntu 17.10 with Axis M3027, Axis M3037, Axis M3048-P cameras.  I'll be testing a Hanwha 12MP Fisheye camera next week.  My input source is h264 via RTSP.  I'm outputting HLS and recording to MP4.

My camera settings ended up being...

- FPS: 15
- Maximum Bitrate: 11000 (Not Variable!)
- Priority: Framerate (instead of Image Quality)
- Dynamic GOP: OFF
- P-Frames: 45 (FPS * 3)

Basically I made the stream as constant as possible.  Eliminate any many variables as you can and modify the ffmpeg options as little as possible. I spent a full day messing with fflags.  In my case I'm copying the vcodec and acodec.

Answer (score 3):

I would try `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` and `-fflags +genpts`

Answer (score 0):

Your input seems to deliver unstable DTS which is just normal for a live input. I recommend to try overriding the input DTS and forcing the output DTS the output DTS, but i did not get out in 5 minutes if that is possible at all.

My luck guess is to play with one of those ffmpeg parameters:

```
-video_track_timescale 25
-filter_complex "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS"
```

let me know if you had any luck!

Comment: Neither seem to help. `-video_track_timescale 25` has no impact. Using `-filter_complex "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS"` results in a bunch of `Past duration. 0.998833 too large` messages and then ultimately ends at `Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0`